# Replace installation types dropdown list by radio buttons

Tags: inno-setup

I recently added different installation types (Install, Update, Repair) to my Inno Setup. It all works pretty fine.

```
[Types]
Name: Install; Description: "Install OLP"; 
Name: Update; Description: "Update an existing version of OLP"; 
Name: Repair; Description: "Repair OLP";
```

The only thing I do not like so much is the dropdown list, that appears when installation runs, to select one of the installation types.

Is there a way to replace the dropdown list by a radio group?

Thanks

Comment: See also [Replacing Inno Setup installation type combo box with radio buttons on separate page (Install Shield like)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50446128/850848).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use radio buttons (since there's no radio group component available in Inno Setup):

```pascal
[Code]
procedure OnTypeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { set the item index in hidden TypesCombo }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := TNewRadioButton(Sender).Tag;
  { notify TypesCombo about the selection change }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  I: Integer;
  RadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
begin
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    { create radio button and set the basic properties }
    RadioButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
    RadioButton.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
    RadioButton.Left := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Left;
    RadioButton.Top := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Top + I * RadioButton.Height;
    RadioButton.Width := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Width;
    { check just the first item }
    RadioButton.Checked := I = 0;
    RadioButton.Caption := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items[I];
    { the Tag property substitutes the index property }
    RadioButton.Tag := I;
    RadioButton.TabOrder := I;     
    RadioButton.OnClick := @OnTypeChange;
  end;
  { hide the TypesCombo combo box }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.Visible := False;

  { if you're not using the "iscustom" flag in any type entry, you can remove }
  { the following lines, because they resize and reposition the check list box }
  { for component selection, which is hidden, if you don't use "iscustom" flag }
  I := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top - 
    (RadioButton.Top + RadioButton.Height + 8);
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top := RadioButton.Top + RadioButton.Height + 8;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height + I;
end;
```

And the result (includes the `iscustom` component list):

[image]

Or you can use e.g. check list box, which is able to contain radio buttons in Inno Setup:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure OnTypeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { set the item index in hidden TypesCombo }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := TNewCheckListBox(Sender).ItemIndex;
  { notify TypesCombo about the selection change }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  I: Integer;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
begin
  { create the TNewCheckListBox object and set the basic properties }
  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  CheckListBox.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
  CheckListBox.Left := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Left;
  CheckListBox.Top := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Top;
  CheckListBox.Width := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Width;
  CheckListBox.Height := CheckListBox.MinItemHeight * 
    WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items.Count + 4;
  CheckListBox.TabOrder := 0;
  { assign the selection change event }
  CheckListBox.OnClickCheck := @OnTypeChange;
  { add radio buttons from all TypesCombo items, select the first item }
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items.Count - 1 do
    CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items[I], 
      '', 0, I = 0, True, nil);
  { hide the TypesCombo combo box }
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.Visible := False;

  { if you're not using the "iscustom" flag in any type entry, you can remove }
  { the following lines, because they resize and reposition the check list box }
  { for component selection, which is hidden, if you don't use "iscustom" flag }
  I := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top - 
    (CheckListBox.Top + CheckListBox.Height + 8);
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top := CheckListBox.Top + 
    CheckListBox.Height + 8;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height + I;
end;
```

And the result (includes the `iscustom` component list):

[image]

Comment: You should scale the radio buttons as per [Scale radio button list with font size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30469660/850848)

Comment: @Martin, you can add comment about scaling to every answer I posted here ;-)

Comment: I found the default selection in the combobox to remember the previous selection (if re-installing) instead of being the very first item. This can cause the example code to have a mismatched default selection between the radio buttons (defaults to 1st item) and the hidden combobox (could be defaulting to non-1st item). I fixed this by forcing the hidden combobox to also always default to the 1st item with this little bit of code: `WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := 0;  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(nil);`

Comment: On second thought my previous suggestion was not ideal, since the default selection is supposed to remember which type you selected when re-installing, so instead I changed `RadioButton.Checked := I = 0;` to `RadioButton.Checked := I = WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex;`

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution for this would be to use [`CreateInputOptionPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createinputoptionpage.htm) to create a separate page with radiobuttons prior to the component selection page.  (There's an example for this in the CodeDlg.iss script.)

An even tidier option is to not ask at all, since it's entirely unnecessary.  You can automatically detect the version that's already installed -- if it's not installed, it's an Install, if it's installed but older, it's an Upgrade, if it's installed and the same version, then it's a Repair, and finally if it's installed but newer then it's a Downgrade -- which you may want to either disallow (safer) or permit but display a warning (more convenient, if it's likely that people might want to downgrade).

Comment: I totally agree on your hints. I will try to improve the setup in future, but currently, the above method from TLama is simpler for me :-)