# Radio buttons to select installation type instead of drop down (combobox) in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there an easy way to make the Types section go in a radio buttons style instead of a dropdown? I searched around but can't really find a good answer for this question.

Like this (courtesy of [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama)):

[image]

Comment: Check box ? That's not a proper control from the UX point of view. Didn't you mean [`radio buttons`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139624/960757) ?

Comment: I mean that when the installer starts you have two options in this case client and complete and this comes in a dropdown . Instead of a dropdown i want two buttons to chose one or the other is this possible?

Comment: ill try it with radio buttons

Comment: Check boxes are for individual settings, not for choosing one option from many. That's what the radio buttons are for. Aren't you going to make something [`like this`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BUM3R.png) perhaps ? I still cannot somehow imagine what you're asking...

Comment: Tlama u can read my mind thats what i want to make yeah

Comment: u got a link or anything so i have an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace installation types Dropdown list by radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130502/replace-installation-types-dropdown-list-by-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to code this using [Pascal Scripting](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptintro).

The simplest solution would probably be to:

- programmatically hide the combobox (drop down)
- create set of radio buttons
- when radio button is checked by an user, programmatically select a corresponding item in the hidden combobox (so that Inno Setup behaves accordingly).

For two alternative examples of implementing this, see:

- [Replacing Inno Setup installation type combo box with radio buttons on separate page (Install Shield like)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50446128/850848) (separate page with radio buttons)
- [Replace installation types Dropdown list by radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130502/850848) (radio buttons on "Select Components" page)

---

Or give up on built-in types completely:

- code new custom page with radio buttons
- select installer tasks using Pascal function, instead of types/components

I'm doing this in my Inno Setup installer.

You can take a look in [WinSCP repository](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/master/deployment/winscpsetup.iss). Though it's bit too complicated (due to a lot of other code).