# Scale radio button list with font size in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When trying to apply a custom installation mask with radio buttons (I used code provided in [Replace installation types dropdown list by radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130502))  I see I am unable to use higher fonts as a little spacing should be needed between one radio button field and another one. To give you a visual example:

[image]

As default font size are not so easy to be read I wonder if there is a way of adding extra spacing between one radio button field and the next one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkboxes and Radio buttons created on runtime in Inno Setup do not scale their height automatically with a DPI/font size.

[image]

So you have to scale them programmatically.

```pascal
...
RadioButton.Left := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Left; 
RadioButton.Height := ScaleY(RadioButton.Height);
RadioButton.Top := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Top + I * RadioButton.Height;
...
```

The `ScaleY(RadioButton.Height)` takes the default combobox/radiobutton height, which is designed for the default font and no display scaling (100%) and scales that to the custom font and actual display scaling.

[image]

---

Though note that using a non-default font-size for your application/setup is not a good idea. The user should choose a font size he/she is comfortable with in Windows preferences. You should not override his/her choice.

---

When changing the font size, do not modify the shared `default.isl`, use the [`[LangOptions]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=langoptionssection) of your project file instead:

```
[LangOptions]
DialogFontSize=20
```