# Conditionally skip to a custom page at the end of the Inno Setup installation wizard without installing?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In Inno Setup below is the code used to detect the *Next* button events,

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  case CurPageID of
    wpLicense:
      begin
        //
      end;
    wpSelectDir:
      begin
        //
      end;
    wpSelectComponents:
      begin
        //
      end;
    wpReady:
      begin
        //
      end;
    wpFinished:
      begin
        //
      end;
    else
      begin
        ///
      end;
  end;
end;
```

There is custom page in place that will be shown after the installation is completed and before the finish dialog. At `wpSelectDir` or `wpSelectComponents` how can you make the installer go to this custom page without installing, when the user chooses so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot skip installation in Inno Setup. But what you can do is to dynamically change the placement of your custom page to show either:

- after the installation (e.g. after `wpInfoAfter`), if the user chooses to install the application, or
- before the installation (e.g. right after the `wpSelectDir`), if not. And [abort the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438506/850848#39788977) afterwards.

```pascal
var
  SkipInstallCheckbox: TNewCheckBox;
  SomePage: TWizardPage;
  
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  SkipInstallCheckbox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm.SelectDirPage);
  SkipInstallCheckbox.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  SkipInstallCheckbox.Top :=
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.DirEdit.Height + ScaleY(8);
  SkipInstallCheckbox.Left := WizardForm.DirEdit.Left;
  SkipInstallCheckbox.Caption := '&Skip installation';
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30469660/850848
  SkipInstallCheckbox.Height := ScaleY(SkipInstallCheckbox.Height);
end;

procedure SomePageOnActivate(Sender: TWizardPage);
begin 
  if SkipInstallCheckbox.Checked then
  begin
    // When skipping the installation, this is the last page.
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  AfterID: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    if SkipInstallCheckbox.Checked then
      AfterID := wpSelectDir
    else
      AfterID := wpInfoAfter;

    // If user returned from the "skip" version of the page and
    // re-enabled the installation, make sure we remove the "skip" version.
    if Assigned(SomePage) then SomePage.Free;

    SomePage := CreateCustomPage(AfterID, 'Some page', '');
    SomePage.OnActivate := @SomePageOnActivate;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  // When skipping the installation, skip all pages after our custom page
  // and before the installation.
  if (PageID in [wpSelectComponents, wpSelectProgramGroup, wpSelectTasks, wpReady]) and
     SkipInstallCheckbox.Checked then
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) and SkipInstallCheckbox.Checked then
  begin
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438506/850848#39788977
    Abort();
  end;
end;
```

---

A related question of yours that improves this: [Can you create a custom page that looks like the Finish page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65619515/850848)

---

Though to avoid all these hacks, consider allowing the installation to proceed normally, but without changing anything. It might be easier to implement in the end.