# Inno Setup - Define Disk Space by component

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

By default, on the components page, Inno Setup adds the size of all the files inside to the size of the selected component (shows on the bottom of the page).

Now, I specifically need Inno Setup to require exactly as much as the current component's size is. How can I achieve that?

New code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Dagon Video Tools
AppVersion=1.0
AppVerName=Dagon Video Tools
DefaultDirName={sd}\Tools\Dagon Video Tools
VersionInfoProductName=Dagon Video Tools
WizardImageFile=Include\WizardImage.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=Include\WizardSmallImage.bmp
SetupIconFile=Include\Icon.ico

[Files]
.....

[ThirdParty]
UseRelativePaths=True

[Components]
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"; Types: Slasher Full
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon Frankenstein"; Types: Frankenstein Full

[Types]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Full"
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon FrankenStein"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Dagon Slasher}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Slasher
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Dagon Frankenstein}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Frankenstein
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Dagon Video Tools}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Slasher and Frankenstein


[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
Begin
if (CurPageID=wpSelectProgramGroup) then
  begin
  if IsComponentSelected('Slasher') then
    begin
      WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExpandConstant('{sd}\Tools\Dagon Slasher');
      WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := 'Dagon Slasher';
    end;
  if IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') then
    begin
      WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExpandConstant('{sd}\Tools\Dagon FrankenStein');
      WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := 'Dagon FrankenStein';
    end;
  if IsComponentSelected('Slasher') and IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') then
    begin
      WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := 'Dagon Video Tools';
    end
  end;
End;

procedure OnTypeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // set the item index in hidden TypesCombo
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := TNewCheckListBox(Sender).ItemIndex;
  // notify TypesCombo about the selection change
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  I: Integer;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
begin
  // create the TNewCheckListBox object and set the basic properties
  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  CheckListBox.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
  CheckListBox.Left := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Left;
  CheckListBox.Top := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Top;
  CheckListBox.Width := WizardForm.TypesCombo.Width;
  CheckListBox.Height := CheckListBox.MinItemHeight * 
    WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items.Count + 4;
  CheckListBox.TabOrder := 0;
  // assign the selection change event
  CheckListBox.OnClickCheck := @OnTypeChange;
  // add radio buttons from all TypesCombo items, select the first item
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items.Count - 1 do
    CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(WizardForm.TypesCombo.Items[I], 
      '', 0, I = 0, True, nil);
  // hide the TypesCombo combo box
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := True;
end;
```

Posted the full code, since, as you can see, my code changes `{app}` and `{group}` depending on the component. I'm gonna have to go to work now, so I'll be offline next half of the day. This code seems to show the correct filesizes, I was going to some other functions attached to component selection, so, if this works I'm gonna have to post another question. Be back in ~8 hours.

Comment: OK, I defined the size of each component (`ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`), but for Inno it's Extra Space, so, when showing the required disk space Inno actually shows the size of all files packed inside + size of the component. I need Inno to disregard the size of the files inside it, and require as much disk space as the current component is.

Comment: So why don't you just set the `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` to number of bytes to top up the size of the files to the size you need? Well, actually that's what the parameter is for.

Comment: OK, the thing is it's a 2-part program. The installer should allow only one program to be installed, or the other, or the "Full Pack". So 2 of the components are less in size than all the files. And the "Full Pack" is already the whole size. Obviously, selecting the "Full Pack" shows double the amount of required disk space. So none of the components' sizes "tops up" upon anything, it should go down.

Comment: It's a component, but all three components are exclusive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using setup components incorrectly. Your *"Full pack"* component is not a component. It is a combination of two components (*"Part 1"* + *"Part 2"*). As a consequence, the built-in Inno Setup logic does not match with your installer and now you ask how to workaround that. Do not try to workaround that, use Inno Setup correctly instead.

What you want is two components:

- *Part 1*
- *Part 2*

and three setup types:

- *Full pack* (installs both *"Part 1"* and *"Part 2"* components)
- *Part 1* (installs *"Part 1"* component only)
- *Part 2* (installs *"Part 2"* component only)

---

If you use components instead of types because you like the "radio-button" selection more than the combo box (drop down menu), see [Replace installation types Dropdown list by radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130502/850848).

This way you get the same GUI as on your screenshot, but working correctly.

In your case it probably does not make sense to show the component list at all. Make sure no type has `iscustom` flag to hide the components list and also to make sure it selects correct components (`iscustom` types do not select their components).

If you want to show the size label anyway, show it explicitly:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := True;
end;
```

If you want to show even the components list with no custom type:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Visible := True;
  WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := True;
end;
```

Comment: That still doesn't show the correct file sizes... Can I just disable Disk Space Requirement in that case? Although, that's still not ideal.

Comment: From the very first days of using Inno, I stayed away from those dreaded types. The "Full" type doesn't show combined filesize, if I switch to another type and then go back to "Full"...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I gotta go to work no, so I'm in a little hurry. And I don't the first thing about Types. I'll be back after work, and post screenshot (Don't know how to post code in the comments, so that'll also be a screenshot)

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin. Of course, it works, I just had to read a little bit about Types and how they work.